# Aligning maximum of plot with x=0

Tags: graphics

In the picture below, I am trying to align the maximum of the ListLinePlot of meandata1 so that it is at x=0. I tried using AxesOrigin, but that only shifted the axes on the graph and not the dataset itself. Could anyone please advise on how I could align the maximum of the plot with x=0, or, in other words, how I could shift the dataset so that the maximum is at x=0? If this matters, the dataset that I am working with is intensity data extracted from an image using ImageData. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Use `DataRange-> {-700,580}`

Answer (score 1):

`DataRange`

Consider:

```
data = Table[Sin[(x - 700)/100], {x, 1, 1280, 1}];
ListPlot[data]
ListPlot[data, DataRange -> {-700, 580}]
```

[image]

[image]